# Convert javascript single page application to bootstrap application

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

We are developing a single page application. There is no html files (except one for loading js and css files. nothing else)
This is an html 5 web application. Today we do not have any problems with browser compatibility. We do not use any third part js libraries. 
We have developed a window handler (with functions for adding inputs, buttons, etc), some library for generic functions (communicating JSON with the webserver, converting date time etc)

But now there is some talk about "converting" to bootstrap and I have no experience with bootstrap. The biggest reason for this is to get a "design where everything match" By far this application has been developed with the focus on the functionality and not the design.

Keep in mind this is not like a company web page but its an application for editing documents, communication etc.

So the question is, should we convert an existing application to bootstrap for the design or should we use a designer to design it now and just convert the design to CSS. Personally I dont like to add all kind of libraries into an application. By my experience is I need much more time to figure how to things work then just write it I pure js and its much harder to debug. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap CSS is fairly simple and you get a lot of bang for the buck just applying bootstrap.css, forgetting anything to do with the bootstrap JS. I don't equate your challenge to "add[ing] all kinds of libraries into an application." If you choose to use the bootstrap classes, you only need to load the bootstrap.css in your master HTML file (and possibly the bootstrap fonts).

Then, of course, the work begins to update your window handler so it not only injects functional HTML elements into the DOM, but also constructs them in the structure that bootstrap expects with bootstrap classes affixed to them. Like any CSS framework Bootstrap has its own set of conventions around how every design element (buttons, dropdowns, tooltips, tabs, and so on) is structured in HTML. This requires that you update WHAT your window handler outputs, but not that you fundamentally change Javascript frameworks altogether.

That said, if you have to put in the time anyway, you might be better off standardizing the app on a well-established framework. The framework will improve over time, both in capabilities and developer support. For the kind of simple, functional app you mention, it seems like it'd be hard to go wrong with AngularJS or ReactJS plus a supported styling framework. If your heart is set on Bootstrap, Angular-UI has a ready-made Bootstrap module, which I'm using on a project right now. It's bootstrap. It fine. Nothing fancy.

My experience is this: If you just want to make every button, field, menu, etc, look consistent and modern, then bootstrap can get you a long way there. But if you want a higher level of UX & brand consistency, CSS standards aren't going to get you there. You need a designer with expertise in doing that, and bootstrap *could* actually hinder you, since it locks you into a particular look and feel that might not be congruent with your brand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only BS CSS if your application otherwise is fine. Or only the parts you need.